# Split string strictly formatted as uppercase letter then numbers into two halves

Tags: php, string, split, text-extraction, text-parsing

I have several strings of the format

> ```
> AA11
> AAAAAA1111111
> AA1111111
> ```

I need to separate the alphabetic and numeric components of the string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If they're all a series of alpha, followed by a series of numeric, with no non-alphameric characters, then [sscanf()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) is probably more efficient than regexp

```
$example = 'AAA11111';
list($alpha,$numeric) = sscanf($example, "%[A-Z]%d");

var_dump($alpha);
var_dump($numeric);
```

Comment: It looks like `sscanf()` is [just a little bit faster](http://viper-7.com/svMSAI) than `preg_split()`. However, the difference is likely negligible.

Comment: One little note, don't use `%[A-Z]%d` because if the numeric part is bigger than 2147483647 you'll get 2147483647 as a result, e.g.: 111111111111111 you could use `%[A-Z]%[0-9]`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using RegEx straight away you can add one extra check for example:

```
if (ctype_alpha($testcase)) {
   // Return the value it's only letters
} else if(ctype_digit($testcase)) {
   // Return the value it's only numbers
} else {
   //RegEx your string to split nums and alphas
}
```

EDIT: Obviously my answer didn't give an evidence which will perform better, that's why I did a test that produced the following result:

1. preg_split took 5.3319189548492 seconds
2. sscanf took 3.4432129859924 seconds

And the answer should have been `sscanf`

Here's the code that produced the result:

```
$string = "AAAAAAAAAA111111111111111";
$count = 1000000;

function prSplit($string) {
    return preg_split( '/([A-Za-z]+)/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}

function sScanfTest($string) {
    return sscanf($string, "%[A-Z]%[0-9]");
}

function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}

$startTime1 = microtime_float();
for($i=0; $i<$count; ++$i) {
    prSplit($string);
}
$time1 = microtime_float() - $startTime1;
echo '1. preg_split took '.$time1.' seconds<br />';

$startTime2 = microtime_float();
for($i=0; $i<$count; ++$i) {
    sScanfTest($string);
}
$time2 = microtime_float() - $startTime2;
echo '2. sscanf took '.$time2.' seconds';
```

Comment: It is always a set of alphas, followed by nums. Will Regex work better than sscanf?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example using [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split):

```
$strs = array( 'AA11', 'AAAAAA1111111', 'AA1111111');

foreach( $strs as $str) 
    foreach( preg_split( '/([A-Za-z]+)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) as $temp)
        var_dump( $temp);
```

This [outputs](http://viper-7.com/rDBwAQ):

```
string(2) "AA"
string(2) "11"
string(6) "AAAAAA"
string(7) "1111111"
string(2) "AA"
string(7) "1111111"
```

Answer (score 0):

[`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) should do the job fine.

```
preg_split('/(\w+)/', $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

The preg library is surprisingly efficient in handling strings, so I would assume it to be more efficient than anything you can write by hand, using more primitive string functions. But do a test and see for your self.

Comment: `preg_split` v/s `sscanf` as @Mark Baker suggested. Would sscanf be more efficient?

Comment: Can't say - I would suggest doing a test. Using preg has the benefit of letting preg do its own memory management. PHP's variables are rather expensive to allocate.

Comment: This answer is provably incorrect. https://3v4l.org/Cvko7

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work but when you try to pass something like "**111111**", it doesn't.

In my application, I am expecting several scenarios and what seems to be doing the trick is this

```php
$referenceNumber = "AAA12132";
$splited = preg_split('/(\d+)/', $referenceNumber, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
var_dump($splited);
```

**Note**:

1. Getting an array of 2 elements, it means the 0th index is the **alpha** while the 1st is the **numerics**.
2. Getting array of just 1 element, means the 0th element is the **numeric** and no alphas.
3. If you get more than 2 array items, then your string must be in this format “AAA1323SDC”

*So given the above, you can play around with it based on your use case.*

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I doubt performance is ever going to be a significant point of concern when comparing `sscanf()` versus `preg_split()`.  The most valuable difference between the two functions is that `sscanf()` has the capacity to cast the numeric substring as an integer -- this can be very handy in (truly professional) applications where type strictness is crucial.

If two string type values are acceptable, then split on the zero-width position after the last occurring letter.  You can safely limit the splits to a max of `2` according to your business requirements.

[Demos of all snippets below](https://3v4l.org/8h3VK)

```
$twoStringArray = preg_split('/[A-Z]+\K/', $input, 2);
var_export($twoStringArray);
// ['AAA', '111']
```

The output from `sscanf()` can be accessed in two ways.

If there are only two parameters passed to the function, then `sscanf()` will return an array of captured values.

```
var_export(
    sscanf($input, '%[A-Z]%d')
);
// ['AAA', 111]
```

If reference variables are nominated after the first two parameters, then `sscanf()` will populate as many variables as it can and return the number of successfully captured substrings.  Note that the reference variables are populated before the count value is returned.

```
$result[] = sscanf($input, '%[A-Z]%d', $result[], $result[]);
var_export($result);
// ['AAA', 111, 2]
```