# Fast way to split alpha and numeric chars in a python string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to work out a simple function to capture typos, e.g:

```
"Westminister15"
"Westminister15London"
"23Westminister15London"
```

after fixating:

```
["Westminister", "15"]
["Westminister", "15", "London"]
["23", "Westminister", "15", "London"]
```

First attempt:

```
 def fixate(query):
     digit_pattern = re.compile(r'\D')
     alpha_pattern = re.compile(r'\d')
     digits = filter(None, digit_pattern.split(query))
     alphas = filter(None, alpha_pattern.split(query))
     print digits
     print alphas
```

result:

```
 fixate("Westminister15London")

 > ['15']
 > ['Westminister', 'London']
```

However, I think this could be done more effectively, and I still get bad results when I try something like:

```
 fixate("Westminister15London England")

 > ['15']
 > ['Westminister', 'London England']
```

Obviously it should enlist `London` and `England` separately, but I feel my function will get overly patched and theres a simpler approach

This question is somewhat equivalent to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477357/php-best-way-to-split-string-into-alphabetic-and-numeric-components) php question

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can get the desired result with `re.findall()`:

```
>>> re.findall(r"[^\W\d_]+|\d+", "23Westminister15London")
['23', 'Westminister', '15', 'London']
>>> re.findall(r"[^\W\d_]+|\d+", "Westminister15London England")
['Westminister', '15', 'London', 'England']
```

`\d+` matches any number of digits, `[^\W\d_]+` matches any word.

`re.split()` would also be possible in current Python versions since splits on zero-length matches are now supported, but the resulting regex is much more complicated, so I still recommend the old approach.

Comment: this gives result as a list. Is there any way to get the value only rather getting a list?

Comment: @shivam: Which value do you mean? If you split a string into multiple items, how can you expect anything but a list?

Comment: I mean is there any way to separate integers and alphabets only rather getting a mixed list? for say I just want integers only from a string.

Comment: @shivam: That's kind of outside the scope of this question because you need to extract substrings instead of splitting a string. Also, you need to specify more precisely: If the string contains "Cost for 4 items: 1.20USD", would you want `1` and `20` among the results? If you do, `re.findall(r"\d+", mystring)` does the trick. If not, it's too complicated for a comment - search for "extract only integers from a string"

Answer (score 16):

Here's another approach in case you prefer to stay away from regex, which sometimes can be unwieldy if one is not familiar enough to make it/change it themselves:

```
from itertools import groupby

def split_text(s):
    for k, g in groupby(s, str.isalpha):
        yield ''.join(g)

print(list(split_text("Westminister15")))
print(list(split_text("Westminister15London")))
print(list(split_text("23Westminister15London")))
print(list(split_text("Westminister15London England")))
```

returns:

```
['Westminister', '15']
['Westminister', '15', 'London']
['23', 'Westminister', '15', 'London']
['Westminister', '15', 'London', ' ', 'England']
```

The generator can be easily modified, too, to never yield whitespace strings if desired.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this regex instead of yours:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r'(\d+|\s+)')
>>> regex.split('Westminister15')
['Westminister', '15', '']
>>> regex.split('Westminister15London England')
['Westminister', '15', 'London', ' ', 'England']
>>>
```

Then you have to filter the list removing empty strings/white-space only strings.