# Elegant parsing of text-based key-value list

Tags: python, regex, parsing, bioinformatics

I'm writing a parser for text-based sequence alignment/map (SAM) files. One of the fields is a concatenated list of key-value pairs comprising a single alphabet character and an integer (the integer comes first). I have working code, but it just feels a bit clunky. What's an elegant pattern for parsing a format such as this? Thanks.

Input:

```
record['cigar_str'] = '6M1I69M1D34M'
```

Desired output:

```
record['cigar'] = [
    {'type':'M', 'length':6},
    {'type':'I', 'length':1},
    {'type':'M', 'length':69},
    {'type':'D', 'length':1},
    {'type':'M', 'length':34}
]
```

EDIT: My current approach

```
cigarettes = re.findall('[\d]{0,}[A-Z]{1}', record['cigar_str'])
for cigarette in cigarettes:
    if cigarette[-1] == 'I':
        errors['ins'] += int(cigarette[:-1])
    ...
```

Comment: Can you show what you have already?  Maybe it actually is the best you can get...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409894/fast-way-to-split-alpha-and-numeric-chars-in-a-python-string

Comment: Unrelated, but please note that `cigarette[-1] is 'I'` is certainly not what you want.  You want `cigarette[-1] == 'I'`.  You should **only** use the `is` operator when comparing to `None` (of course this is a generalization, but if you find yourself using `is` you should ask yourself why and determine if it really is what you want).

Comment: @SethMMorton Thanks! I'd suspected it was a bad habit.

Comment: Yes. `is` checks that two object's id's are the same, which is rarely what you want unless you are doing something fancy (or magical). `==` checks that two object's values are the same, which is what you want in just under 100% of all cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I'd do:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '6M1I69M1D34M'
>>> matches = re.findall(r'(\d+)([A-Z]{1})', s)
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint([{'type':m[1], 'length':int(m[0])} for m in matches])
[{'length': 6, 'type': 'M'},
 {'length': 1, 'type': 'I'},
 {'length': 69, 'type': 'M'},
 {'length': 1, 'type': 'D'},
 {'length': 34, 'type': 'M'}]
```

It's pretty similar to what you have, but it uses regex groups to tease out the individual components of the match.

Comment: Regex groupings coupled with a generator seems to be what I was after. Thank you.