# Splitting a roll string using Regex (i.e. 4d6dl1kh2)

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I have been trying to find a way to parse roll-like strings (i.e. `4d6dl1kh2`) into something like `{(4,6),Args[(dl,1),(kh,2)]}`. I could easily do it if I could split the string into `['4','d','6','dl','1','kh','2']`, but I'm still not sure.

This question is similar to [Fast way to split alpha and numeric chars in a python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409894/fast-way-to-split-alpha-and-numeric-chars-in-a-python-string#), however, I'm not sure how to alter it to not care about spaces.

In the link listed, they used the following regex expression:

```
re.findall(r"[^\W\d_]+|\d+", "23Westminister London")
>> ['23', 'Westminister', 'London']
```

And I want it to do...

```
re.findall(r"Something", "23Westminister London15 Paris France")
>> ['23', 'Westminister London', '15', ' Paris France']
```

Or, in my case, the dice expression I gave above.

I can't read the regex for the life of me. How do I alter it?

Comment: Can't you create a list using `re.findall(r'\d+|[a-z]+', '4d6dl1kh2')`. What spaces are you talking about in a roll-like string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're telling you're accepting /digits, or word+space/.

so `\d+|[a-z\s]+` should do the job

https://regex101.com/r/VeD3Yu/1

Comment: Thanks for that link! That tool seems VERY helpful.

Comment: Once you've learned the many tools in the first screen, take a look at the (step by step) debugger screen. It is very helpful to understand the internals of regexp.