# How to calculate molecular weight of a molecule in python efficiently with less memory consumption?

Tags: python-3.x, coding-efficiency

Here is my code to calculate molecular weight(H2O, NO2, CO2, HCOOH) using predefined values of elements in a dictionary.

```
mass = {"H":1, "O":16, "C":12, "N":14}

def moleculeMass(moleculeName):
  p = 0
  total = 0
  for i in moleculeName:
    if i.isalpha():
      p = i
      total += mass[i]
    else:
      total = total - mass[p] + (mass[p] * int(i))
  return total

compoundName = input("input molecule name: ")
print(moleculeMass(compoundName))
```

In the above `else` statement there is an extra step of subtracting the total from **existing** mass of element if a number is encountered after a letter. How can I eliminate this extra check?

Comment: Which part of you calculation is not efficient, or is using too much memory?

Comment: As a side note, your code won't work for two-letter atoms, such as Cl or Mn.

Comment: BTW: Your code fails to calculate the mass for [Butane (C4H10)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butane)

Comment: `total = total - mass[p] + (mass[p] * int(i))` -> `total += mass[p] * (int(i)-1)`

Comment: For two-letter (or more) and/or two-numberic (or more) you could use: [Fast way to split alpha and numeric chars in a python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409894/fast-way-to-split-alpha-and-numeric-chars-in-a-python-string/12411196)

Comment: @DYZ I knew that my program wouldn't work for two-letter atoms or two-digit numbers that's why I provided the name of eligible compounds in a bracket.
Btw, thanks for simplifying the 'total' variable in the `else` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code already seems fairly quick as is, but if you want to get rid of what you see as extra code, you might:

```
def moleculeMass(moleculeName):
    total = 0
    for i in moleculeName:
        if i.isalpha():
            mass_p = mass[i]
            total += mass_p
        else:
            total += mass_p * (int(i) -1)
    return total
```

As other have pointed out, this will not support multi digit definitions.

If you wanted to support molecules like `Cl2O2` or `C4H10` then you might try a regex split, but it will be slower than what you have now:

```
mass = {
    "H" : 1,
    "O" : 16,
    "C" : 12,
    "N" : 14,
    "Cl" : 35
}

re_pattern = re.compile(r"([A-Z][a-z]?|\s+)")

def moleculeMass2(moleculeName):
    total = 0
    for symbol in [symbol for symbol in re_pattern.split(moleculeName) if symbol]:
        if symbol.isalpha():
            prior_mass = mass[symbol]
            total += prior_mass
        else:
            total +=  prior_mass * (int(symbol) - 1)
    return total
```

That should give you the proper weights for:

```
print(moleculeMass("NO2"))
print(moleculeMass("C4H10"))  # wrong answer
print(moleculeMass("Cl2O4"))  # key error

print(moleculeMass2("NO2"))
print(moleculeMass2("C4H10"))
print(moleculeMass2("Cl2O4"))
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the issue @JonSG !
I also learnt more about list comprehensions and generator expressions.