# Split an Address Line in PHP

Tags: php

I'm using a the Royal Mail Postcode database to make sure I get the correct address details on my form. It pulls through the address into my form using the relevant input boxes. this is great, but I want to do is in the first input box the address may be something 
123 The Street or Apartment 29 or even HouseName The Street. I post these within my form.

So the post is something like $_POST["line1"];

How is it possible to split the line into sections so that I can take the HouseNo or House Name from the address, so that on my next page I can show it as HouseNo/Name & Street Name?

Using the examples above output `echo $houseno; - 123, echo $street; - The Street`

Comment: provide another form element for address line 2

Comment: `explode($_POST['line1'], ' ')` perhaps? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to split in two parts numeric and alpha

```
$example = $_POST["line1"];
list($alpha,$num) = sscanf($example, "%[A-Z a-z ]%d");

echo $alpha; // address in alpha with space
echo $num; // house no
```

For more :- [PHP: Best way to split string into alphabetic and numeric components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477357/php-best-way-to-split-string-into-alphabetic-and-numeric-components)

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use regular expressions to try and split up characters. Admittedly you'd then [have two problems](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

In general you're not going to find this very easy to do. You've posted some testcases:

- 123 The Street
- Apartment 29
- "The Orchard"

Here's a couple more to think about:

- 1A The Street
- Flat B

Rather than attempting to process a free-form field with (literally) thousands of possible variations, why not provide an interface on the Royal Mail database (which you say you have)? Many sites give this option now:

1. You enter your postcode and (usually) house number
2. A box shows a list of matching addresses to choose from

You still get addresses which exactly match the Royal Mail database, but you now get the customer to do the tricky address-matching part of the process.

Of course, you should probably still let people enter freeform address data because the address database is sometimes a few steps behind reality...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I should have explained what I want to do with the address split. I have the ability for the customer to enter their Postcode and then search for their address using a SELECT option, just as you said above. What I want to do is on my next page use the House Number say to create a Job Number with the Postcode for example if the Line1 was 123 The Street and Postcode was T1 3ST then my Job Number would be 123T1 3ST. This is what I'm wanting to achieve

Comment: OK - thanks. That makes more sense. If you just need to extract a contiguous chunk of digits then you could use the following regex: `(\d+)` and then append the postcode. I'd probably caution against doing this, though. What if you have three flats under the same number? What about business addresses where many offices will share the same number? Is it OK for the job number to be the same if the same customer orders more than once?

Comment: I have a dropdown option for the Job Type so this will form the start of the JobNumber so that I can have the same customer on different Job Types